# Ruby on Rails : Handle Database connection failure/timeout with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, database-connection, digital-ocean, connection-timeout

I am about to move my production PostgreSQL DB to a managed DB from Digital Ocean. So, there is a possibility for a down time during the maintenance/back up procedures which may last up to 10 seconds. How to effectively handle this DB down time without getting the rails application crashed? I read about 'reconnect: true' in database.yml. But not sure it will work for PostgreSQL. Any suggestions?